Issue with '<= applied to 6 arguments' in Haskell
I'm trying to write a function that determines whether a list of positive Ints is either a) increasing or decreasing and b) the absolute difference between successive numbers is at least 1 and less than 3.
Here's my attempt:
isSafe :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool -> Bool
isSafe [x] _ _ = True
isSafe (x:xs) 0 isIncreasing = isSafe xs x isIncreasing
isSafe (x:xs) prev True = (x-prev >= 1) and (x-prev < 3) and isSafe xs x True
isSafe (x:xs) prev False = (x-prev <= -1) and (x-prev > -3) and (isSafe xs x False)

The 2nd parameter is the previous element and the 3rd parameter is whether the list is increasing.
I'm getting this error:
example.hs:23:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(t2 Bool -> Bool)
                                    -> Bool -> (t3 Bool -> Bool) -> Bool -> Bool’
                  with actual type ‘Bool’
    • The function ‘(<=)’ is applied to six value arguments,
        but its type ‘Int -> Int -> Bool’ has only two
      In the expression:
        (x - prev <= - 1) and (x - prev > - 3) and (isSafe xs x False)
      In an equation for ‘isSafe’:
          isSafe (x : xs) prev False
            = (x - prev <= - 1) and (x - prev > - 3) and (isSafe xs x False)
   |
23 | isSafe (x:xs) prev False = (x-prev <= -1) and (x-prev > -3) and (isSafe xs x False)

Could someone help me understand why <= is applied to 6 values?
Thanks!

Replace and with &&. The message is cryptic indeed, but it originates from the fact that and in Haskell is a different kind of function with type and :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool, and is obscuring the problem here. (The discussion about the whole Foldable business is probably beyond what's needed to resolve your issue here.)

and is not a binary (infix) operator in Haskell, but a normal function from the standard library.
Therefore, x and y calls function x with two parameters, namely and and y.
Similarly, x and y and z calls function x with four parameters, namely and, y, and, and z.
And so on. This is not what you intended.
If you need the logical conjunction of several boolean expressions, you need to use x && y && z && ... or, alternatively, and [x, y, z, ...]. The former uses the && binary infix operator. The latter applies the and library function to a list of boolean values.

The and :: Foldable f => f Bool -> Bool function [Hackage] takes a Foldable of Bools, like a list for example, not two Bools.
You can use the (&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool function [Hackage] instead:
isSafe :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool -> Bool
isSafe [] _ _ = …
isSafe [x] _ _ = True
isSafe (x : xs) 0 isIncreasing = isSafe xs x isIncreasing
isSafe (x : xs) prev True = (x - prev >= 1) && (x - prev < 3) && isSafe xs x True
isSafe (x : xs) prev False = (x - prev <= -1) && (x - prev > -3) && (isSafe xs x False)
You should probably also implement a base case for the empty list.
